# R remove empty (nchar = 0) elements from list of lists

Tags: r, list, nested-lists, sapply

I have a list of lists/vectors:

```
list(c("cat1", "cat6", ""), c("cat5", "cat3", "cat4"), c("cat6", 
"cat4", ""), c("cat5", "cat1", "cat2", "cat4"), c("cat6", "cat3", 
"cat2"))
```

and I'm looking an elegant way to remove inner elements with nchar=0 like the 3rd element in the first list (with value "").
I have tried:

```
l[lapply(l,length)>0]
```

but that does not apply to the inner elements length but to the external list elements length.
The expected output is:

```
list(c("cat1", "cat6"), c("cat5", "cat3", "cat4"), c("cat6", 
    "cat4"), c("cat5", "cat1", "cat2", "cat4"), c("cat6", "cat3", 
    "cat2"))
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: You can try `sapply(l, function(x) x[nchar(x) > 0])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `nzchar` to create a logical index of TRUE/FALSE for non-blank/blank elements and then subset the `list` elements.

```
lapply(l, function(x) x[nzchar(x)])
```

Or another option is `setdiff` to remove the element that are `''` from each of the `list` elements.

```
lapply(l, setdiff, '')
```

---

The `length` function will count `''`, so it will not be of much help in removing the `''`.